# Conditional Random Forest Predict Error, Error in kids_node(node)[[i]] : subscript our of bound

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest, missing-data, imputation

I estimate my sample 70 variables with many predictors X have missing values with 70000 Obs.  Y is binary variable with 5% of observations = 1 and 95% = 0

```
cf <- cforest (formula = Y ~., data = df , 
               perturn = list (replace = FALSE, fraction = 0.5, 0.5), 
               control = ctree_control (MIA = true), ntree = 1500, mtry=8)
```

I encounter a problem when I predict with OOB prediction with its own within-sample.
It returns the error of

```
Error in kids_node(node)[[i]] : subscript out of bounds
```

Sometimes, I change the seed, it solves the problem. But the identical error message shown up when I predict the out of sample.

Anyone encountered similar issue?

Answer (score 0):

When you change the seed it solves the problem hmmm. I am not 100% sure, but I will try to provide 2 explanations that might be the problem.

1. You use predictory variables that aren't present in your OOB predictions. Let's say you use the number of cars per person as a predictory variable, but your OOB predictions do not contain information regarding the number of cars per person. This results in an error.
2. It could be that at times you are using information for your prediction, that isn't available in your OOB prediction.

So to specify this. Let's say your RandomForest is trained on a categorical variable called 'state'. The model learns that the state = Arizona is associated with a lower probabilty and the state = California is associated with a higher probability. However, in your OOB predictions you have the state = Washington. The model doesn't know this category and will provide an error as it is not trained on this variable specification.

*Another tip that is not related to this question is that given that 5% of observations = 1 and 95% = 0, I would take a look at class imbalance. I suspect that your predictions will be biased towards the majority class (this doesn't have to be the case, but if it is, take a look at class imbalance techniques such as sampling)*